# CSS selector for multiple matching elements for Selenium

Tags: css-selectors

I'm trying the select the second element using the below css selector, first element is selected but second element is not selected. Not sure what I'm missing here.

Below is my HTML code:

And CSS selector I'm using - `div[id='bootstrapContainer']` `form[id='course_form']:nth-of-type(1)` to select the first instance, which is working.

But- `div[id='bootstrapContainer'] form[id='course_form']:nth-of-type(2)` is not selecting the second instance

Comment: It's usually seen as bad practice to have more than one id of the same name on the page, classes can have multiple instances but an id should be unique.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type: _“The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches one or more elements of a given type, based on their position among **a group of siblings**.”_ Your `form` elements aren’t siblings here; they are both _the only_ child of their `div.form` parent - so each of them is the first, last, _and only_ of its type in its group of siblings all at the same time. That is why it seems to work for the first instance, but not for any of the following.